# Is it possible to change what architecture you are using in python?

Tags: python

I installed python 2.7.13 on an iMac running macOS Mojave version 10.14.6. I am trying to execute a program in 32 bit mode, but it is running in 64 bit mode. Since my version of pygame is 32 bit, it gives me an error. I found a tutorial on how to find out what architecture of python you are using; you just have to type this code:

```
import struct
print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)
```

And it prints a number that is the architecture you are using. I was wondering if it is possible to run a program in 32 bit mode, or if i will have to find another version of pygame.

Side note: I am running it from the python website provided IDE, not from the python preinstalled on the mac, so I would like to avoid terminal commands if possible

Comment: Why not just grab 32 bit python?

Comment: @KieranMoynihan I've tried, but the only version of python 2.7 i can find contains both 64 bit and 32 bit in the same installer. I dont know how to switch between them. As an aside, however, having both 32 and 64 in one application is much more convenient than needing a seperate version for each. However, if you can redirect me to an only-32 bit python 2.7 installer, I could use that as well.

Comment: can't you use `pip` to install PyGame for your Python?

Comment: I cant seem to install pygame for python 2.7 using pip - i can only install pygame for python 3.7.

Comment: can't you use python 3.7 ?

Comment: I am following a tutorial that is inherent to python 2. It also uses a server component that I would have to upgrade manually.

Comment: Can you try https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/python-2.7.14-macosx10.5.pkg

Comment: Thank you! I will try that when I get home and update this.

Comment: [Python 2.7 will retire in...](https://pythonclock.org/)

Comment: @JustinEzequiel this didnt work. I got the error "Idles subprocess didnt make connection. Either IDLE Cant start a subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection.